# get authors with articles older than 11 months

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to echoing all authors with articles older than 11 months.
But there is nothing as result.

My date column is like this - `2017-07-01 05:00:00`

```
    $d = date("F 1, Y", strtotime("-11 months"));
// also tried:
    $d = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n')-11, 1, date('y'));

    $items = '';

    $sql = "select * from posts where date < " . $d;
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $db -> execute();
    while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
        $items .= "<div class='auth'>" . $row['auth'] . "</div>/n";
    }

    echo $items;
```

Comment: You don't seem to execute your query.

Comment: You need to execute the query `$db->execute();`

Comment: You don't need to compute dates in PHP. The database is able to do all the work, if you ask it nicely.

Comment: *sigh*. `$st->execute()`. And please, if you're going to make an edit that completely changes the problem you've posted, at least leave a comment, or add a note to your question...

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and getting errors

Comment: Read about [MySQL date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) then ask the database nicely to `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH)`. Also read about the PHP [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and [its friends](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). `mktime()` is out of fashion for a decade now.

Comment: Which are.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a query that returns a distinct list of authors with books published more than 11 months ago.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AUTH
FROM posts
WHERE `date`<DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 11 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query in your PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 11 MONTH)";
```

Comment: trhere is no error now, but nothing as a result. I'm sure there are such posts.

Comment: First run your query in phpmyadmin and see the results